# Logo in Bootstrap NavBar shifts hamburger to the left when browser is small

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I was trying something today. In a Bootstrap NavBar, if the logo (navbar-brand) is text only then the hamburger stays on the right. But if the logo is an image, the hamburger shifts to the left when you resize the browser. I can't figure this out.

I'm currently working on Angela Yu's Udemy course and completed the Bootstrap module. Now trying to use what I learned to re-create my own website.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="title">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/techsnazzy-logo.png" width="30%" height="30%" alt="TechSnazzy Logo" />
      </a>
      <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse id=" navbarSupportedContent>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">Home</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKvuT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-nowrap` bootstrap class to your `navbar`. Read some information on the documentation here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#wrap

From **w3schools**

> The flex-wrap property specifies whether the flexible items should
>   wrap or not.

Also avoid to use width and height on logo image because it creates extra space between logo and nav-item like this:

[image]

Use `width: 30%` on `.navbar-brand` instead and set `width: 100%` to logo image.

I updated your code, please check:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id="title">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light flex-nowrap">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="width: 30%;">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" alt="TechSnazzy Logo" class="w-100" />
      </a>
      <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse id=" navbarSupportedContent>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">Home</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Oh awesome! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Your welcome! If this solves your problem please feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I didn't know I needed to do that. Ok, I'll do it now.

Answer (score 0):

The toggler is simply getting wrapped to the next line, based on the width of `.navbar-brand` and this is expected behavior for it to then be left-aligned. If you want the toggler to always be right-aligned, adding the class `ml-auto` appears to work.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" ...
```

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#auto-margins

Comment: I would love to agree, but it doesn't. First, I don't want the toggler to wrap it to the next line. That is unexpected behavior. Second, it doesn't work. With a text only logo it works as expected. But with an image logo, the hamburger shifts to the left (or bottom depending on how you look at it).

Comment: What browser are you using? at what screen width? Can you edit the image src attribute in your snippet to be an absolute URL?

Comment: The behavior may be unexpected by you but in the examples on the bootstrap site they do in fact wrap when the screen is too narrow, and once wrapped they are left aligned. So you should expect your code to behave in the same manor without further modification.

Comment: Sorry, I worded it wrong. I mean, I would think (my expectation) that the hamburger should stay to the right by default whether it's an image or an anchor element. Both are inline elements so I would think they should behave the same? Or maybe I'm just not understanding this completely.